# Define CSS variables from Django Models

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create an app where the user would be able to customize the design. As for now, I would like to make something very simple and just let the user define the value of some colors like this:

```
class PageSettings(models.Model):
    base_color = ColorField(default='#FFFF00')
```

mi css file define variables like this:

```
:root {
  --blue: #0061f2;
  --indigo: #5800e8;
  --purple: #6900c7;
  --pink: #e30059;
  --red: #e81500;
  --orange: #f76400;
  --yellow: #f4a100;
```

I'm wondering if there's a way where I can tell mi CSS file not to use some color, let's say 'blue' as #0061f2, but insted use the value of 'base_color'.

Comment: As long as you are defining the CSS inside your `django` template, you can probably return the value from your view as a context variable and use it as `--blue:{{ my_color_val}}`

Comment: Hi Abhyudai, actually mi css in its own file.

Comment: Then you can't populate values from `django` in it.